# Состояние для каждого элемента в компоненте

Tags: javascript, reactjs

У меня есть компонент который рендерит список элементов с подэлементами. Отдельный элемент вынесен во внешний компонент, чтобы каждый элемент имел свое состояние, но почему то по нажатию на один элемент, состояние меняется у всех элементов(раскрываются все элементы). Только начинаю погружаться в реакт, подскажите пожалуйста в чем моя ошибка?

Первый компонент с выводом списка

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import classes from './Catalog.module.css';
import CustomInput from '../CustomInput/CustomInput'
import Item from './Item/Item'

const Catalog = (props) => {

  const [somethingData, setSomethingData] = useState([]);
  const [inputValue, setValue] = useState('');

  const getData = () => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3001/somethingData')
      .then(response => setSomethingData(response.data))
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getData()
  }, []);

  const filterData = somethingData.filter(item => {
    return item.title.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue.toLocaleLowerCase())
  })

  const renderItem = (items) => {
    return <Item key={items.id} filterData={filterData} />
  }

  return (
    <div className={classes.catalog}>
      <CustomInput setValue={setValue}/>
      {renderItem(somethingData)}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Catalog;
```

Второй компонент с рендером элемента

```
import classes from './Item.module.css';
import { useState } from 'react';

const Item = (props) => {

    const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setVisible(!visible)
  }

  let elementData = props.filterData.map(el => 
    <div key={el.id}>
      <div className={classes.title} onClick={handleClick}>
        {el.title}
        <div className={classes.line}></div>
        <div className={classes.showed}> {visible ? 'скрыть' : 'показать'} </div>
      </div>
      {visible ? el.dataSection.map(e => 
        <div className={classes.content} key={e.key}> 
          <a href={e.url} target='blanck'> { e.section } </a>
        </div>) : null}
    </div>
  )

    return (
        <div>
            {elementData}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Item;
```

Мой json файл

```
  "somethingData": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "title": "Первый элемент",
      "dataSection": [
        {
          "key": "1",
          "section": "Подэлемент",
          "url": "http://google.com"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "title": "Второй элемент",
      "dataSection": [
        {
          "key": "1",
          "section": "Первый подэлемент",
          "url": "http://yandex.ru"
        },
        {
          "key": "2",
          "section": "Второй подэлемент",
          "url": "https://ru.reactjs.org/"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В функцию `renderItem` я добавил `map` функцию по данным, которая отображает каждый `Item`. Вот рабочий вариант как можно сделать:

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
// import CustomInput from "../CustomInput/CustomInput";

const Catalog = (props) => {
  const [somethingData, setSomethingData] = useState([]);
  const [inputValue, setValue] = useState("");

  const getData = () => {
    setSomethingData(data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  const filterData = somethingData.filter((item) => {
    return item.title.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue.toLocaleLowerCase());
  });

  const renderItem = () => {
    return filterData.map(({ id, title, dataSection }) => {
      return <Item key={id} title={title} dataSection={dataSection} />;
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {/* <CustomInput setValue={setValue} /> */}
      {renderItem()}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Catalog;

const Item = ({ title, dataSection }) => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setVisible(!visible);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      Title: {title}
      <button onClick={handleClick}> {visible ? "скрыть" : "показать"} </button>
      {visible
        ? dataSection.map(({ key, section, url }) => (
            <div key={key}>
              <a href={url} target="blank">
                {section}
              </a>
            </div>
          ))
        : null}
    </div>
  );
};

const data = [
  {
    id: "1",
    title: "Первый элемент",
    dataSection: [
      {
        key: "1",
        section: "Подэлемент",
        url: "http://google.com",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    title: "Второй элемент",
    dataSection: [
      {
        key: "1",
        section: "Первый подэлемент",
        url: "http://yandex.ru",
      },
      {
        key: "2",
        section: "Второй подэлемент",
        url: "https://ru.reactjs.org/",
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался благодаря Вам как это работает!) У Вас в слове title была опечатка, минут 5 не мог понять почему не отображаются заголовки)

Comment: Круто, пожалуйста, да titel это по немецкии ))